# Hibernate SessionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

```
private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

        public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
    }
```

What is SessionFactory class?
Why do we use it?
What is hibernateTemplate Class used for?

```
<bean id="myUserDAO" class="com.mysticcoders.mysticpaste.services.ContactSerImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.mysticcoders.mysticpaste.model.Contact</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

What does this do in bean

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Application obtains session instances from Session Factory.
`SessionFactory` is mostly configured as `Singleton` in application ,
If you are using Spring it will be configured in application context to be made singleton.

`SessionFactory` caches generate SQL statements and other
mapping metadata that Hibernate uses at runtime.

Cached data that has been read in one unit of work and may
be reused in a future unit of work.

You can obtain object of session factory from Configuration class

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory =
Configuration.buildSessionFactory();
```

Here in your conf. you have configured sessionFactory using AnnotationSessionFactoryBean class

```
bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
```

and you have set some properties of session factory those are needed.

`HibernateTemplate` is a class provided by Spring :

> Helper class that simplifies Hibernate data access code. Automatically converts HibernateExceptions into DataAccessExceptions, following the org.springframework.dao exception hierarchy.

Answer (score 6):

1. ***SessionFactory*** is as Interface it delivery the of session object for whole application or entire hibernate application.
2. There will be generally one ***SessionFactory*** and can be shared
   by all application thread. ***SessionFactory*** is thread-safe.
3. ***SessionFactory*** is second level cache of data that is reusable between transaction at a process or cluster level.

   ```
                                                                         Continue.......
   ```

Answer (score 3):

SessionFactory contains all the hibernate mapping informations and it is responsible for creation and maintenance of the hibernate session in a transaction.